# How can I access the object variable in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

My defined class in Python:

```
class jpg(Abc):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(jpg, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.TAG = 'tag'
        self.PARAMS = {}
```

I import this class in Robot framework:

```
Import Library  jpg    host=${ip}   WITH NAME   jpg
```

How can I call PARAMS in Robot Framework?
I tried with `${jpg.PARAMS}` or `jpg.${PARAMS}`, but it didn't work

I want to do 2 actions on this variable: set and get

Comment: The extended variable syntax in the RobotFramework user guide is a good reference to understand custom objects access. http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax

Answer (score 6):

You can create a new python keyword to use the class.
It may like this:

`class_test.py`

```
class jpg(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.TAG = 'hello tag'
        self.args = args
        self.PARAMS = {}


def test_jpg(*args, **kwargs):
    return jpg(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, you can use it in your robot files like this:

`test.robot`

```
*** Settings ***
Library         class_test.py


*** Test Cases ***
python class test
    [Tags]    class
    [Documentation]    python class test
    ${ret}=    test_jpg    class_tag
    Log    ${ret.TAG}
    Log    ${ret.args}
```

log file like below:
[image: log_file]